# Playframework 2.2 adding dependency

Tags: playframework

I'm struggling with a new project using Playframework 2.2. My problem is that I can not find any Build.scala. Is it normal? why? I couldn't find it.

I also tried to add a Build.scala from an old project (the project works perfectly) but then I got an error when launching play:

```
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Please provide more information so we can reproduce the problem. Since Play 2.2 the build configuration is in build.sbt instead of project/Build.scala: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify these in the `build.sbt` file like so:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  // "group" % "artifact" % "version"
)
```

Make sure you have empty new lines before and after that block.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. Actually I had no build.sbt but adding those lines to plugins.sbt works fine.

Comment: If you created a new Play 2.2 project then you should have had a `build.sbt` file.  The `plugins.sbt` is usually for adding sbt plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one can use build.sbt or project/build.scala or even both with play2, but if you are generating new application with play2 2.2 build.sbt is default place to add dependencies

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies

and

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but I recently ran into an issue like this and after 3 hours of searching, the internet seems to not contain an answer to this which suffices.

**To use sbt with Eclipse**

1. Be sure that sbteclipse is added to your plugin definition file (or create one if doesn't exist).

   - You can use either:

     1. The global file (for version 0.13 and up) at
        ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt
     2. The project-specific file at PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt
2. In your terminal run:
   `activator eclipse`
3. Highlight your project in the Eclipse Solution Explorer and hit `F5`
4. Import whatever you were trying to import originally

The `activator eclipse` command will tell activator to build the eclipse files necessary based on your `build.sbt`